# Como bloquear o redimensionamento de um widget/janela?

Tags: python, qt, gui, pyqt, pyqt-4

Estou definindo uma determinado widget de acordo com o tamanho do monitor secundário.

Isso eu consegui fazer perfeitamente. Porém, como sou iniciante com PyQt, gostaria de saber como faço para bloquear o redimensionamento da janela.

Quero dizer, quero que o usuário não possa maximizar, minimizar ou redimensionar esse widget.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Código atual:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class RetroProjetorWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, desktop, parent=None):
        super(RetroProjetorWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(desktop)

    def setupUi(self, desktop):
        self.setGeometry(desktop.screenGeometry(1))
        # Quero bloquear o redimensionamento aqui...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta ficar o mínimo e máximo

```
self.setFixedSize(200, 200);
```

Variações:

```
setFixedHeight (self, int h)
setFixedSize (self, QSize)
setFixedSize (self, int w, int h)
setFixedWidth (self, int w)
```

Você pode usar algo como (este seria preferencial para limitar entre um range):

```
self.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
self.setMaximumSize(300, 240)
```

Podendo usar as variações como:

```
setMaximumHeight (self, int maxh)
setMaximumSize (self, int maxw, int maxh)
setMaximumSize (self, QSize s)
setMaximumWidth (self, int maxw)
setMinimumHeight (self, int minh)
setMinimumSize (self, int minw, int minh)
setMinimumSize (self, QSize s)
setMinimumWidth (self, int minw)
```

Acredito que para usar o `QDesktop` você deve fazer algo como (neste caso usei `desktop.primaryScreen` para pegar o monitor principal, isto pode variar):

```
 screenSize = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen())
 self.setGeometry(screenSize)
```

Você pode trocar `desktop.primaryScreen()` por `desktop.screen(0)` ou conforme a necessidade.

Documentação: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html